# LINQ to SQL Associations Not Generating

Tags: .net, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I created a basic database via SQL Server, with the tables generated by the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Characters]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [RefName] varchar(8) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [SkypeHandle] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CharacterOwnership]
(
    [CharacterID] int NOT NULL,
    [PlayerID] int NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CharacterOwnership_ToCharacters] FOREIGN KEY ([CharacterID]) REFERENCES [Characters]([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CharacterOwnership_ToPlayers] FOREIGN KEY ([PlayerID]) REFERENCES [Players]([ID]),
)
```

Dragging the tables over from Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012, I generated the following diagram:

[image: Automatically Generated ERD]

As far as I can tell, I set up the primary keys and foreign keys correctly.

With

```
var db = new DBClassesDataContext();
```

LINQ is able to access every table, and any field of that table without issue. However it *cannot* bring up associated tables.

I have setup another project with LINQ to SQL (with another database) in the past few days and didn't have this issue before. Googling around everyone else who has had this issue that I can find had it because the PKs and FKs were not correctly configured, however as before stated they *appear* correct to me. (If they're not, feel free to point out the error of my ways!)

I have also followed advice saying to close Visual Studio and reopen, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured it out. For those who might come across this via Google:

**Every table, *even association tables*, must have primary keys. No exceptions.**

I'm not sure why--logically--this would need to be the case, but I imagine it's some background nature of LINQ to SQL.

Comment: "For those who might come across this via Google"

That was me today. So thank you for taking the time to post the solution.